# tooltip shown with page load / popup position under chrome extension icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating a browser action chrome extension - the user need to press a button.
I want that with any page load a tool tip will appear on the icon telling the user what he can do by pressing the button.
Can I show a tooltip with any page load? or - I thought I can open a popup that explains the icon  with content script - the question is how can I place this popup near the icon - can i some how know the position of the icon?

Thank you!

Comment: What part of the [api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) are you having trouble with?  You get tooltips, popups, and icons basically automatically.

Comment: @Teepeemm The OP probably wants to create some UI pointing to the browser action button. Kind of like programmatically opening the popup (which is impossible).

Comment: The tooltip - only shown when hovering over the icon - i am looking for a tooltip that shown with any page load of the user. if its impossible - can i know some how the position of the icon - so i can open a small popup (showing the tool tip text really) with page load - i can use content script. but how can i place it under the icon?